# How do I pass the same object across multiple classes java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an object class that I want to use across multiple classes. Basically, I want this object to be used as a place where I can dump information into, and then unpack that information.

Let's say for example I have 5 classes

Class1 will return a box object. --> Foo(object) will store the box

Class2 will return a snake object. --> Foo(object) will store the snake

Class3 will return a circle object. --> Foo(object) will store the circle.

Class4 will return a a food object. --> Foo(object) will store the food

Class5 will return a box, snake, circle, and food object. --> unpack Foo(object) to return the box, snake, circle, and food object.

How can I do this? If possible can you provide some sample example code for this kind of scene? Let me know if any more clarification is required.

Comment: So you want a class wrapping your object? That's already the role of the `Object` class.

Comment: For this kind of problem, code isn't even fully necessary to answer it either. I just need some guidance.

Comment: But let's say you declare the Foo object in class 1. How can I declare the same foo object in class 2? The fact is you can't. So how can I store information as such. For example,
class class1{
   Foo a = new Foo();
a.setbox();
}
class 2 {
Foo a = new Foo()
a.setSnake();
}

There are two instantiations of object a. Isn't each instantiation different from the other?

Comment: There is a reason we ask you for code. SO isn't meant for us to write the code for you. Please show what you have tried so far and then ask a specific question about the specific issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it :

1. create a class that you will create your object as an instance of it.
2. make this class extended from Serializable class (allowed you to freeze and in freeze, you object)
3. use intent to navigate between your activities and add your object as an intent data.

Edit
That's work with activities!
**SECOND way**

What if you make your object invoke its data from class extended from Sharedpreferences like

Create an object from class A which its constructor uses Sharedpreferences class to fill object data

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `interface` with a `dump` method and implement the `interface` with all the classes you intend to work with. If your `interface` is called `Dumper`, you will need to implement it in all the classes where you intend to use it, if possible. If not, for instance, class `EvilGuy` is out of your control, you can simply create an `EvilGuyWrapper` `class`, with a member of `EvilGuy` and implementing `Dumper`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a collector, right?

Create a class that will accumulate objects:

```
public class EventCollector {
    private List<Object> events = new ArrayList<>();
    public void add(Object e) {
        events.add(e);
    }

}
```

Pass EventCollector instance to your box, snake, food, circle objects:

```
public class Circle {
     private EventCollector ec;
     public setEventCollector(EventCollector ec) {
         this.ec = ec;
     }

     public void pack() {
         ec.add(this);
     }
}
```

Do the same for food, box, snake, etc... Call pack method on all of them.

All objects will be in the EventCollectior at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When working in Java remember that the language leans heavily towards having information available at *compile time*.

What you want to do is essentially to determine this at runtime, and you can only do this by returning the object and casting it to the class you expect at that point.

In your case, you need to either have a common superclass of all the different types you want to store, an interface implemented by all the types or just use Object.   You can store it in any collection of this, like ArrayList.

Then when you get the object back you need to use "instanceof" to find out what you are looking at, and then cast it to the appropriate type.

Note that this is tedious and error prone, and you may want to reconsider and learn generics.